# Stream PubSub to Spanner - Wait.on Step

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-pubsub, google-cloud-spanner

Requirement is to delete the data in spanner tables before inserting the data from pubsub messages. As MutationGroup does not guarantee the order of execution, separated delete mutations into separate set and so have two sets, one for Delete and other to AddReplace Mutations.

```
PCollection<Data> dataJson =
        pipeLine
            .apply(PubsubIO.readStrings().fromSubscription(options.getInputSubscription()))
            .apply("ParsePubSubMessage", ParDo.of(new PubSubToDataFn()))
            .apply(Window.into(FixedWindows.of(Duration.standardSeconds(10))))
        ;
SpannerWriteResult deleteResult = dataJson
        .apply("DeleteDataMutation", MapElements.via(......))
        .apply("DeleteData", SpannerIO.write().withSpannerConfig(spannerConfig).grouped());

    dataJson
        .apply("WaitOnDeleteMutation", Wait.on(deleteResult.getOutput()))
        .apply("AddReplaceMutation", MapElements.via(...))
        .apply("UpsertInfoToSpanner", SpannerIO.write().withSpannerConfig(spannerConfig).grouped());
```

This is a streaming dataflow job and I tried multiple Windowing but it never executes "UpsertInfoToSpanner" Step.

How can I fix this issue? Can someone suggest a path forward.

**Update:**
Requirement is to apply Two Mutation Groups sequential on same input data i.e. Read JSON from PubSub message to delete existing data from multiple tables with mutation group and then insert data reading from the JSON PubSub message.

Comment: I think this is a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58280581/pubsub-to-spanner-streaming-pipeline) on SO. Can you please check the answer it was provided  there.

Comment: @marian that is different problem than this. Thanks for checking.

Comment: The Mutation operations within a single MutationGroup _are_ guaranteed to be executed _in order_ within a single transaction, so I don't see what the issue is here...  The reason why Wait.on() never releases is because the output stream that is being waited on is on the global window, so will never be closed in a streaming pipeline.

Comment: @RedPandaCurios I have two mutation groups one for delete and other for insert, my requirement is to execute delete mutation group before insert mutation group execution.

Comment: I realise that, but there is no way to guarantee order of mutation group execution, and SpannerIO executes in the global window so you cannot wait for one path to finish in streaming mode. Only solution is to put the deletes and the inserts into the same mutation group if possible, or use InsertOrUpdate mutations.

Comment: Note that although you say that your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58280581/pubsub-to-spanner-streaming-pipeline) is different (even though it appears on the surface to be the same), the answer provided there may well be valid for this question,

Comment: @RedPandaCurios thank you for clarification. I had tried to put all in one mutation group but it did not work as expected. Will try once again and check if this works out.

Answer (score 0):

Re-pasting the comment earlier for better visibility:

The Mutation operations within a single MutationGroup are guaranteed to be executed in order within a single transaction, so I don't see what the issue is here... The reason why Wait.on() never releases is because the output stream that is being waited on is on the global window, so will never be closed in a streaming pipeline.

Comment: how can I execute delete mutation group before insert mutation group execution?

Comment: @SagarKC
See above: currently not possible with SpannerIO in streaming mode.